# java heap size increasing and out of memory

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, visualvm

I use java visual VM to monitor my heap and i see that the heap dump is showing bad signs
[image]

I think that this is why I am running out of memory,

How to limit the "size" (orange area) ?

Comment: Check this out:- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v7r5m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.wbpm.admin.doc%2Ftopics%2Fctun_zos_redinchpoutofmem.html

Comment: Are you redploying the application multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

Since your used heap size is stable, you can limit maximum heap size by using -Xmx512m to limit it to 512 MB for example.

This is a good article on what proper sizing should be (a bit out of date though):
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/tools/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.igaa%2F_1vg00014884d287-11c3fb28dae-7ff6_1001.html

Edit:
Since I see youre using NetBeans profiler, to set the option, just right click your project > Properties > Run > VM Options: -Xmx512m

Comment: +1 In this case it doesn't reach above ~330 MB.  You could set the limit to be `-Xmx256m`